# Google Sheets - Drag Formula that skips rows

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to drag down rows that contain formulas that skip a row. It seems to me that it worked at one point, and now I can't for the life of me get it to work right. There are several cells that I hoped would auto-increment. I have marked in red the problem rows. [image: example]

It's my intention that cell A8 would ='Area Counts'!G8 as opposed to ='Area Counts'!G10, and A10 to ='Area Counts'!G9 respectively. I was also needing the formulas in columns b, c, d, etc. to auto increment as well.

I had a version where it worked and I was able to grab the first 4 rows, drag down 50 rows or so, but when I tried to extend to over 100, I ran into this issue that I've now spent the day researching and fiddling with. Now I can't get it to drag-fill anything correctly.

Any advice, solution, or direction to research would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the same behavior and it seems that Google Sheets auto-increments cells based on the number of highlighted active cells.

But, here is a **workaround**:

You can use `=FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA({Area Counts!H6:H13,Percentages!C2:C9}))`

Sample Implementation:

I used `=FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet2!A1:A17,Sheet3!C9:C25}))` in my case

[image]